# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign' while attempting transfer learning

Tags: python, keras, transfer-learning

I based my attempt on the example from https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part3.ipynb#scrollTo=BMXb913pbvFg
and attempted transfer learning for a classification of cats and dogs, then did the same for an example of "Zebra and elephants" and encountered no issues.
The code for my example was almost the same as the tutorial and worked:

```
image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255., validation_split=.2)
image_size = 128
IMAGE_WIDTH = image_size
IMAGE_HEIGHT = image_size
BATCH_SIZE=128
image_data_dir = "images"
seed = 1
image_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode='rgb', 
    subset='training',
    seed = seed,
    class_mode='binary')
test_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode='rgb', 
    subset='validation',
    seed = seed,
    class_mode='binary')

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
inputs = Input((image_size, image_size, 3))
vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling=None, input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3), classes=2 )

for layer in vgg16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in vgg16.layers:
  print(layer.name, layer.trainable)

x = Flatten()(vgg16.get_layer('block5_pool').output)

x_ = BatchNormalization()(x)
x_ = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x_)
x_ = BatchNormalization()(x_)
x_ = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x_)
x_ = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x_)

model = Model(vgg16.input, x_)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='Adam',
                  metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit_generator(image_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=n/BATCH_SIZE, 
                    epochs=50,
                    validation_data=test_generator)
```

This code encountered no trouble.
The following one throwed the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-55354bac5e27> in <module>()
     43     validation_data=test_generator,
     44     validation_steps= 458 // BATCH_SIZE,
---> 45     epochs=90)

--> 228   return ref.assign(value, name=name)
    229 
    230 

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

here it is:

```
image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255., validation_split=.15)

image_data_dir = "processed/img/"
seed = 1 
IMAGE_SIZE = SIZE
IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT = IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE

image_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="categorical", #could be "binary" for binary problems
    color_mode='rgb', 
    subset='training',
    seed = seed)

test_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    image_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="categorical", #could be "binary" for binary problems
    color_mode='rgb', 
    subset='validation',
    seed = seed)

layer1 = Input((SIZE, SIZE, 3))

vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling=None, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3), classes=num_classes )

for layer in vgg16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

bnorm = BatchNormalization(name="14")(vgg16.get_layer('block4_pool').output)

conv = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name="13")()
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),name="15")(conv)
pool = BatchNormalization(name="16")(pool)

x = Flatten()(pool)

x_ = BatchNormalization()(x)
x_ = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x_)
x_ = BatchNormalization()(x_)
x_ = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x_)
x_ = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x_)

model = Model(vgg16.input, x_)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adadelta',
                  metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit_generator( image_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= 2606 // BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps= 458 // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=90)
```

To my knowledge, There are a few useless lines ( such as the creation of an input layer that is not used in the architecture i end up with.

Generally, i think both cases are pretty similar, i only made a few changes due to the fact that the new problem has 3 classes instead of 2.

Unfortunately googling that error didn't help much. Does anybody see an error i made ?

Comment: Firstly, change `conv = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name="13")()` to `conv = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name="13")(bnorm)`. Secondly, check the folder containing your images for the problem seems to be arising from the `image_generator`. I tried your code on my machine with a small dataset of mine, and it is training without any issues (both 2 and 3 classes).

Comment: Thank you for your input ! I also rewrote from scratch and i was baffling to find the seemingly identical code working now :) maybe it had something to do with the first suggestion you gave.